# If array_key_exists() is deprecated in PHP7.4, then how to use the alternative like isset() or property_exists() to array?

Tags: php, arrays, object, key, array-key-exists

I've already trying `array_key_exists()`, but when it should return the expected result, lumen display error message that I need to use another php function instead of `array_key_exists()` like `isset()` or `property_exists()` as mentioned in this question title.

```php
$jsonData = "mydata.json";
$content = file_get_contents($jsonData);
$unsortedData = json_decode($content, true);

//convert array to object
$object = (object) $unsortedData;

$key = $request->input('key');
$keyData = "false";
if(array_key_exists($key, $object))
{
    $keyData = "true";
}

// usort($unsortedData,  function($a, $b){
//     return $a['no'] > $b['no'];
// });
return $keyData;
// var_dump($unsortedData);
```

Which one should be used and how to use it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`array_key_exists()`](https://www.php.net/manual/function.array-key-exists.php) used to work with objects but that behavior was deprecated in PHP 7.4.0 and removed in PHP 8 :

> Note:
>
> For backward compatibility reasons, array_key_exists() will also
> return true if key is a property defined within an object given as
> array. This behaviour is deprecated as of PHP 7.4.0, and removed as of
> PHP 8.0.0.
>
> To check whether a property exists in an object,
> [property_exists()](https://www.php.net/manual/function.property-exists.php)
> should be used.

So, you can change your code to :

```
// Take note that the order of parameters is inverted from the array_key_exists() function
//                    |       |
//                    V       V
if(property_exists($object, $key))
{
    $keyData = "true";
}
```

Comment: i think your answer is correct, but when i just test it locally with my data from this question [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69612633/how-to-convert-array-to-arrayobject-with-php-from-json-file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69612633/how-to-convert-array-to-arrayobject-with-php-from-json-file) it's always false.

Comment: also, here's the result from postman  
`var_dump($object);` and result:
`object(stdClass)#15 (100) { ["0"]=> array(25) { ["no"]=> int(1) ["serial_number"]=> int(123456789) ["id_register"]`

Answer (score 1):

While the above answer solves the issue for some cases, it doesn't when you have protected/private properties.

I used array_key_exists to check if the property was private/protected, where the last ones would be marked with an asterisk by the function and return false, cos the name mismatches.

I solved this like this:

```
array_key_exists($key, (array)$obj);
```

So type casting the object should solve it even in php8.
I think in php 7 and earlier this was being done under the hood. In 8 they removed it, maybe performance issues??

Answer (score -1):

A lot of people recommending property_exists($object, $key) but it is for objects or class properties not for an array.
It will return an error if you check array.

**First parameter must either be an object or the name of an existing class**